# Using a variable in WHERE statement column name

Tags: mysql

This is not working. My column names include Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun set to 0 or 1. I am trying to see if column name is 0 or 1 based on the 3-digit current day of the week.

```
SET @var = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a') 
SELECT *, @var 
FROM team LEFT JOIN fav ON team.Tag = fav.Tag WHERE ID = '123456' AND @var = '1' 
ORDER BY team.Name
```

Comment: Why do you need the `SET`? Why not just put that in the condition?

Comment: I initially tried $var=date('D');
WHERE $var='1' but that did not work

Comment: You can't dynamically select a column name. That's equivalent to `SELECT *, '1'` for Monday. Consider making your data [properly relational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) so you can do this query without a lot of fuss.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: You'll need to look up database normal forms and better understand how to relate your data to make this query more concise. It should be a one-to-many relationship between one row and the various on-day-X table with other rows.

Comment: I need more help.

Comment: I can't walk you through every little step here. You're going to need to invest some time in absorbing these concepts so you can create relational schemas. "Database normal forms" is a very deep rabbit hole to go down, but the principles are pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable's `@var` value is a string literal and can't be used as a column.
You can do what you want with a `CASE` expression:

```
SET @var = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a'); 
SELECT *, @var 
FROM team LEFT JOIN fav 
ON team.Tag = fav.Tag 
WHERE ID = '123456' 
AND '1' = CASE @var
  WHEN 'Mon' THEN Mon
  WHEN 'Tue' THEN Tue
  WHEN 'Wed' THEN Wed
  WHEN 'Thu' THEN Thu
  WHEN 'Fri' THEN Fri
  WHEN 'Sat' THEN Sat
  WHEN 'Sun' THEN Sun
END
ORDER BY team.Name;
```

Or without the variable:

```
SELECT * 
FROM team LEFT JOIN fav 
ON team.Tag = fav.Tag 
WHERE ID = '123456' 
AND '1' = CASE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a')
  WHEN 'Mon' THEN Mon
  WHEN 'Tue' THEN Tue
  WHEN 'Wed' THEN Wed
  WHEN 'Thu' THEN Thu
  WHEN 'Fri' THEN Fri
  WHEN 'Sat' THEN Sat
  WHEN 'Sun' THEN Sun
END
ORDER BY team.Name;
```

Inside the `CASE` expression qualify the columns Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun with the table (`team` or `fav`) they belong.

Comment: The `SELECT ..., @var` part doesn't really help here, nor the static `'1'`, but the `CASE` is definitely the way to tackle this problem.

Comment: The static '1' is the OP's code from the WHERE clause, so why doesn't it help? The @var maybe is not needed in the select list but it's up to the OP to decide.

Comment: I think it's an artifact of some confusion, when really what's intended is `SELECT ..., CASE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a')...` instead, or even better, `DAYOFWEEK(NOW())` instead of the `DATE_FORMAT` excursion.

Comment: The OP thought that by setting: `SET @var = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a');` then the variable could be used in place where a column like `Mon` can be used. This is the reason of the use of the variable. Sure the code can be written without it by using a function inside the CASE statement.

Comment: Thank you @forpas for the solution to my question. Worked beautifully. I ended up dropping the variable and going with 
SELECT * 
FROM team LEFT JOIN fav 
ON team.Tag = fav.Tag 
WHERE ID = '123456' 
AND '1' = CASE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a')
  WHEN 'Mon' THEN Mon
  WHEN 'Tue' THEN Tue
  WHEN 'Wed' THEN Wed
  WHEN 'Thu' THEN Thu
  WHEN 'Fri' THEN Fri
  WHEN 'Sat' THEN Sat
  WHEN 'Sun' THEN Sun
END
ORDER BY team.Name;
Thanks again.